# How to permanently redirect from one base url to another in IIS 7

Tags: redirection, iis-7

I have a website hosted on IIS7 configured with following two host headers

```
members.company1.com
members.company2.com
```

I now need to permanently redirect `members.company1.com` to `members.company2.com`. I know how to redirect a complete url to another relative url with same base address. But how to redirect from one base address to another configured on same website?

```
==UPDATE==
```

So I tried following instructions from the answer below and from [this blog post](http://oneidia.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/simple-http-redirect-with-querystring.html). But now IIS returns `HTTP 302` and the location returned has `Dedault.aspx` added to the end, no matter what the original URL was. Does anyone know where can I find documentation for mysterious `$V` and `$Q` variables of IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website Host Redirect

This is relatively simple to achieve in IIS with the HTTP Redirect function.

1. Create a new folder for your redirect website
2. Create a new website in IIS, the sole purpose is redirect
3. In the website settings choose "HTTP Redirect"

   - tick "Redirect request to this destination"
   - enter "members.company2.com"
   - choose the type of redirect
4. move the old host header from the website with two headers, to the redirecting website

Comment: @Peter.tindale that got me going but I am facing another problem now. See the updates to original question. Any idea what is happening?